# Is it safe to assume read stream 'end' event gets triggered after 'fs.writeFileStream' is done writing and closing a file after a pipe?

Tags: node.js, stream

I hesitate on what is the best solution between these snippets:

```
simple_client({
    method: 'get',
    path: key,
    id: 'download'
})
    .then(req => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const write_stream = fs.createWriteStream(path);
        req.on('result', (err, res) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            }
            res.pipe(write_stream);
            res.on('end', () => {
                console.log('Done!');
                resolve();
            });
        });
        req.end();
    }))
    .then(() => {  
        console.log(`Is it safe to touch ${path} file here?`);
    });
```

or

```
simple_client({
    method: 'get',
    path: key,
    id: 'download'
})
    .then(req => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const write_stream = fs.createWriteStream(path);
        req.on('result', (err, res) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            }
            res.pipe(write_stream);
            write_stream.on('finish', () => {
                console.log('Done!');
                resolve();
            });
        });
        req.end();
    }))
    .then(() => {  
        console.log(`Is it safe to touch ${path} file here?`);
    });
```

[Readable pipe documentation](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/stream.html#stream_readable_pipe_destination_options) says:

> By default, stream.end() is called on the destination Writable stream when the source Readable stream emits 'end'

So am I right to assume the file is fully written and closed when 'end' event has been emitted from the readable stream? Therefore first snippet would be good enough. Thanks for your help!